# Building a UEFI bootable USB

Tags: grub2, live-usb, iso, uefi

I'm having a really hard time getting Mint13 installed on my new laptop, no optical UEFI support and having odd corruption of grub.cfg when I do try and use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Is there a method to build a UEFI bootable USB drive that I can place the Mint13 iso on?

Is below sane sounding?

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/boot
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
$ sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/iso/
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/grub/scripts
```

Save [autoiso.cfg](http://www.mail-archive.com/grub-devel@gnu.org/msg16403/autoiso.cfg) script in the /mnt/boot/grub/scripts

```
Then echo 'configfile /boot/grub/scripts/autoiso.cfg' >> /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the tools recommended on http://pendrivelinux.com? They will make this much less painful.

Comment: Yea I tried that. It couldn't find an OS on the drive, even though it did come up.

Comment: Did you try some of the unetbootin alternatives they link to? I seem to recall having similar problems with a Mint install (might have been LMDE) and the same machine booted fine from a USB created by [multisystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/).

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by getting on a friends windows machine, and using rufus, and selecting the "MBR Partition Scheme for UEFI or BIOS Computers" and it booted up showing the UEFI prefix on the flash drive.

Odd that it didn't see it with just GPT and UEFI.